# Safari stops playing audio after user login

Tags: safari, audio

This was happening since Sierra for me and it's still here now on Mojave. Every time, when closing my macbook over night (just switch user to login screen, no logout or shutdown), if I don't quit Safari, the next day when I login the audio is completely silent in Safari. The system audio is still working and songs in Finder/iTunes play normally, but not Safari.

But the really annoying part is that the only way (I found to work) to get the sound back was to restart the whole system. Restarting just Safari did nothing, logout/login did nothing, killall Safari nothing, etc.

Does this happen to anyone else too? Do you know of any way to fix the sound, other than rebooting the computer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found out what the issue was. I have Loopback installed for capturing system audio for screen recordings and it is set to start automatically on login, muting the audio from Safari but it then doesn't pass the audio through to the system output.